# Joining two tables, which in one there are multiple Lines related to a single line from the other table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need help figuring out how to solve a problem I face when trying to inner join 2 tables,which in one there are multiple Lines related to a single line from the other table. explenetion below-

Wasn't able to figure out how to do this, any help will be highly appreciated!

In `table1` I have the columns `USERID` , `name` and `age`. The key is the `USERID`.

In `table2` if I have the columns `USERID` and `number`. there can be multiple different numbers lines for each ID, the keys are the `number` and the `USERID`.

I want to create an SQL code which gives me a random line from `Table1` on the condition that the age is *32* (for example),
and that in `Table2` the same USERID doesn't appear in a line in which there is the *number* 3 (for example).

`table1` looks like

```
USERID | NAME | AGE
  5    |  joe | 32
```

and in `table2` I have the lines `|USERID - 5, number - 5|` and `|USERID - 5, number - 1|` it will be ok, and Joe will be included in the random poll, but if i also got `|USERID - 5, number - 3|` then he wont.

```
USERID | NUMBER
  5    |   5
  5    |   3
  5    |   1
```

I already figured out how to do this but without using the `table2` connection, what I got was

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
,Rnd(USERID) 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Age = 32 
ORDER BY Rnd(-(100000*USERID)*Time()) DESC_;
```

I would appreciate if your help would be with my random-line-getting technique, as others don't work in the program I'm using.

Comment: Your question is not clear (at least not to me), but in any case you should tell us whether you are using Access or SQL Server.  Both happen to have a `TOP` operator, so we can't tell just based on your code.

Comment: HI, its via access

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! This question was *so close* to being good. A couple of readability edits and you'll do fine on this site. Make sure that your SQL scripts are encapsulated by backticks or use Ctrl+K to create a shortcut and it will `make your scripts more legible`.

As for the post. You need to declare variables as constraints for your USERID ranges, otherwise you risk having an out-of-bounds USERID and not returning any rows.

```
DECLARE @MinUSERID INT = 1;
DECLARE @MaxUSERID INT = 100;
DECLARE @USERID INT;
```

Now you'll be able to set a random USERID value for your tests.

```
SET @USERID = SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*(@MaxUSERID -@MinUSERID +1))+@MinUSERID 
              FROM table1
              WHERE Age = 32;
```

Using this random @USERID variable you can SELECT from table2 to return the tests you want this individual to perform, but this will return all tables. It's unclear what the process is to omit tables, but you explicitly said you don't want to include `NUMBER=3` in your result set. If you want to omit a random poll you can just replicate the `RAND()` clause posted above

```
SELECT *
FROM table2
WHERE USERID = @USERID
AND NUMBER <> 3
```

To write this as one query you can draft a select statement similar to this:

```
DECLARE @MinUSERID INT = 1;
DECLARE @MaxUSERID INT = 100;

SELECT t1.NAME
     , t1.AGE
     , t2.USERID
     , t2.NUMBER
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.USERID=t2.USERID
WHERE t1.Age =32
AND t1.USERID=FLOOR(RAND()*(@MaxUSERID -@MinUSERID +1))+@MinUSERID 
AND t2.NUMBER <> 3
```

This is written for SQL Server, not ms-access but it should pretty easy to translate this to the other language

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks for your help! but there are still a few problems, first of all, FLOOR doesn't work in access, and so does the DECLARE function. So i changed your code a bit to work with access, and it gives me an error which was my main problem from the first place, that says: "the specified USERID filed may reference to more than one table in the from sentence in the sq. sentence" (its a translation so it might not 100% be like the English error version) my code was – (see next comment)

Comment: `SELECT t1. NAME , t1.AGE , t2.USERID, t2.NUMBER, Rnd(t1.USERID) FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.USERID=t2.USERID WHERE t1.Age =32 AND t2.NUMBER <> 3 ORDER BY Rnd(-(100000*USERID)*Time()) DESC;` would appreciate you helping.